# In C language,is it wrong to declare str[i]='\0' in the declaration part of a for loop to obtain the the value of 'i' at the last character?

Tags: c, for-loop, reverse, c-strings

I tried writing a code to reverse a string, but without calculating the length of a string.

after i gave the input it is showing segmentation fault, please help...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char nor[10], rev[10];
  int i, d = 0, j;
  printf("enter\n");
  scanf("%s", nor);
  for (i = 0; nor[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    for (nor[j] = '\0'; j < 10; j--) {
      if (i == d)
        rev[i] = nor[j];
      d++;
    }
  }
  puts(rev);
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to obtain the value of j at the point where the string ends,so in the inner for loop i mentioned `nor[j]='\0'`, but it seems this is the part that is ruining the code, but the logic i gave looks fine to  me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Does you compiler tell something about using variable `j` without assigning a value first?

Comment: `for (nor[j] = '\0'` doesn't look right.  Your loop variable isn't `nor[j];` it's `j`.  To find the starting value for j, you first need to search for \0 in the string, or use the ending value of `i`.  Then you can run your inner `for` loop.

Comment: and `j` has no value assigned before then.

Comment: You've got a probable buffer overflow problem — the arrays `nor` and `rev` are (too) small.  You should restrict the input, and check that a valid input was received — `if (scanf("%9s", nor) != 1) { …report error; do not continue… }`. (The off-by-one on the sizes is irksome but unavoidable.  If you change the array sizes to something more sensible — using 80 or 1024 — adjust 9 too.)  The assignment `nor[j] = '\0'` is dubious because (a) `j` is not initialized and (b) you truncate the string.  You'll need to null-terminate the reversed string.  You've got some serious rethinking to do.

Comment: and either the comparison or the decrement in `for (nor[j] = '\0'; j < 10; j--)` must be wrong.

Comment: I _think_ you want [this](https://godbolt.org/z/dxcnshG63) but the current code seems so full of confusion that I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: BTW, you can write `nor[j] = 0` instead of `'\0'` without any problem. Don't see a reason to decrease readability and write unnecessary characters.

Comment: @i486 -- using `'\0'` instead of `0` communicates the intent of using a null terminator; this aids readability when that is the intent.

Comment: @adabsurdum Char `\0` means byte 00 which is exactly `0`.

Comment: @i486 It's pretty clear that both are the same, isn't it? Admitted, I personally prefer the shorter `0` as well (and consider it more readable, too), but some prefer a *character literal* (which in C actually is of type `int` – I know…) to denote that they want to place a *character* containing the null value into a string – in the end a matter of taste, so I wouldn't argue about further ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua -- agree that it is a matter of taste, and readability is somewhat subjective. I usually prefer to use `'\0'` when specifying a null terminator since `0` needs context. But I usually prefer `0` when initializing string buffers, e.g., `char strbuf[1024] = { 0 };`, although I'll probably switch to `char buff[1024] = {};` with C23.

Comment: @adabsurdum Admitted, seeing some isolated `*s = '\0';` we have an hint already that `s` is a `char` array or pointer to… But I personally would feel a bit at the wrong place if I didn't know that already before ;) Not sure how I should interpret that intermixed usage of both styles – is that an inconsistency? Again you'd need context, but that is provided in the same line anyway (the justification for?)...

Comment: @adabsurdum By the way, `char strbuf[1024]; *strbuf = 0;` would be – assuming it is intended to store a C-string – cheaper, just initialising what really *needs* to be initialised ;)

Comment: my compiler didn't show any error for not initialising the value of 'j', it generally takes as '0' if not mentioned.

Comment: @Robert Harvey doing as you said is the same as finding the length of a string, which I don't want to find.

Comment: @Sarvani Typically you start reverting the string from its end – and for that you need to find this end first... On the other hand: You could start filling the reversed buffer from its end, then you'd need just one single iteration.

Answer (score 2):

In the inner for loop

```
for (nor[j] = '\0'; j < 10; j--) {
```

when initially `j` has an indeterminate value because it was not initialized

```
int i, d = 0, j;
```

the assignment

```
nor[j] = '\0'
```

already invokes undefined behavior.

Bear in mind that using the conversion specification `"%s"` is unsafe. The user can overwrite the character array used as an argument for such a conversion specification.

And also using the variable `d` does not make any sense. The variable `d` is just redundant.

You can not reverse a string without knowing its length.

So first, you need to determine the length of a string and then to reverse the string.

And pay attention to that you are not trying to reverse a string. You are trying to copy a string in the reversed order in another character array.

If you want to reverse a string then the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char nor[10];

    printf( "Enter a string: " );
    
    if ( scanf( "%9s", nor ) == 1 )
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        while ( nor[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
        {
            char c = nor[i];
            nor[i] = nor[n - i - 1];
            nor[n - i - 1] = c;
        } 

        puts( nor );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to copy a string in the reversed order from one character array to another character array, then the program can look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char nor[10], rev[10];

    printf( "Enter a string: " );

    if ( scanf("%9s", nor ) == 1 )
    {
        size_t n = 0;

        while ( nor[n] != '\0' ) ++n;
        
        rev[n] = '\0';

        for ( size_t i = 0; n-- != 0; i++ )
        {
            rev[i] = nor[n];
        }
  
       puts( rev );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dropping any lines not referring to `j` variable all that remains is:

```
int i, d = 0, j;
// ...
for (nor[j] = '\0'; j < 10; j--)
```

`j` isn't ever assigned a value anywhere – thus it contains some arbitrary garbage value most likely provoking undefined behaviour due to accessing an array out of its bounds, resulting in given case in a crash (but that's not necessarily the case, just *anything* could happen upon UB, the programme crashing right away, crashing at some later seemingly totally unrelated point of time, running but showing weird behaviour or seemingly running fine).

Side note: Something similar could be provoked by the user by entering too long data, as you do not prevent that on scanning the input (especially as your array is really short). To be on the safe side try `scanf("%9s", nor)`.

Then for reversing there's no nested loop needed anyway, but two individual loops; first one to look up the end of the string, second one to do actual reversing, which might look as follows:

```
char* n = nor;
while(*n)
{
    ++n;
}
// now n points to the end of the string

for(char* r = rev; n-- != nor; ++r)
//                 ^ check first, then decrement:
//                   we are behind current character to copy
//                   once we are equal there are no characters left
{
    *r = *n;
}
*r = 0; // terminate the reversed string
```

*Edit (inspired by [Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76915438/1312382); with pointers appears more elegant to me, though):*

You can even revert *in place*, allowing to drop the second array entirely:

```
char* n = nor;
while(*n)
{
    ++n;
}
--n; // don't want to include the null terminator in reversal
for(char* r = nor; r < n; ++r, --n)
{
    char c = *r;
    *r = *n;
    *n = c;
}
// null terminator remained untouched anyway, so no action necessary
```

Note, though, that any pointer comparison other than (in-)equality is only legal if both pointers point to the same array, which is the case here, of course...

*Edit (inspired by the comments to the question): A single iteration variant (*requiring *two buffers).*

If you want to iterate just once you might fill the target buffer from its end:

```
char* r = rev + sizeof(rev);
*--r = 0;
for(char* n = nor; *n; ++n)
{
    *--r = *n;
}
// r now points to the begin of the reverted string...
```

(If you insist on operating with indices: Initialise `i` to `0`, `j` to `sizeof(rev)` and do the equivalent to above with these; then you'll find the reverted string at `rev + j`).

Answer (score 1):

I think here is a really interesting problem.
First of all, the `nor[j] = '\0'` line is problematic.
I will try to explain it. What value does `j` have? If you do `nor[j] = '\0'`, `j` will not take the index of the last element from the `nor[]` array. `nor[j] = '\0'` mean that in the `nor[]` array, at the `j` position you want to put `'\0'`.
I think you got the segmentation fault, because when you declare `j` without a value here `int i, d = 0, j;`, it takes a random value, like 571239. So, when you do `nor[j]='\0'` you want to access the 571239th position from the `nor[]` array which doesn't exists.

So to answer your question, yes, it is wrong to declare `str[i]='\0'` in the declaration part of a for loop to obtain the the value of `i` at the last character.

Comment: Put backticks around bits of code in the text to format them.